# SED: Displaying the first 10 lines of sophisticated expression

Tags: linux, bash, sed

How to use sed to find lines with the word linux? As later display a first line 10 with the word linux?
EX.:

```
cat file | sed -e '/linux/!d' -e '10!d' ### I can not display the first 10 lines of the word linux

cat file | sed '/linux/!d' | sed '10!d' ### It is well
```

How to make it work with one sed?

```
cat file | sed -e '/linux/!d; ...?; 10!d'
```

...? - storing of the buffer linux? 10 later cut the lines?

Someone explain to me?

Comment: grep linux file | head -10

Comment: or `grep -A 10 linux file` or `grep -m 10 linux file` depending on particular task.

Comment: Neither -A nor -m does what the user is looking for, alas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/linux/{p;G;/(.*\n){10}/q;h}' file
```

Print the line if it contains the required string. If the required number of lines has already been printed quit, otherwise store the line and previous lines in the hold space.

Comment: What simple. I struggled a week and gave up. Thank you.

Comment: @user2435244 I would give this answer the accept. You asked for `sed` potong provided (clear) `sed` :) (Although I still think awk is better here)

Answer (score 5):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '/linux/ && c<10 {print;c++} c==10 {exit}' file
```

Comment: @JS웃 Yeah! looks better :) awk rocks!!! Will keep my answer so that others can still see how it can be shortened by yours.

Comment: Absolutely. Since OP seems to be a beginner, verbosity would do him good! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'if (/linux/) {print; ++$a;}; last if $a==10' inputfile
```

Using GNU sed:

```
sed -rn "/linux/{p;x;s/^/P/;ta;:a;s/^P{10}$//;x;Tb;Q;:b}" filename
```

Comment: In this case I would prefer `sed` as it is more clean and readable ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, `sed` is always more _readable_.  In this case, other examples (i.e. perl and awk) look rather obfuscated in comparison :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. You are great. All of the examples look very nice. Wooow :) It is a pity that I can not do that.
I have not seen for 'r' option in sed. I need to learn.

```
echo -e 'windows\nlinux\nwindows\nlinux\nlinux\nwindows' | sed -nr '/linux/{p;G;/(.*\n){2}/q;h}'
```

It works very well.

```
echo -e 'windows\nlinux\nwindows\nlinux\nlinux\nwindows' | sed -nr '/linux/{p;G;/(.*\n){2}/q;h}' | sed '2s/linux/debian/'
```

Can I ask you one more example? How to get a result at one sed?